# Extend &:hover of any class to any other class's hover in SASS or SCSS

Tags: html, css, sass, hover

Is there a way to extend `&:hover` of any class to any other class's hover?

My code is something like this and it stopped the hover of both classes:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="button1">Button 1</a>
<a href="#" class="button2">Button 2</a>
```

**SCSS**

```
.button1 {
  background: black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  &:hover {
    background: red;
  }
}

.button2 {
  background: blue;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  &:hover {
    @extend .button1:hover
  }
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/3f1c5b1538239b572700

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a placeholder.

```
%hover {
  background: red;
}

.button1 {
  background: black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  &:hover {
    @extend %hover;
  }
}

.button2 {
  background: blue;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  &:hover {
    @extend %hover;
  }
}
```

Or, perhaps a better solution, use a more generic class for your buttons:

```
.btn {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;

  &:hover {
    background: red;
  }
}

.btn--1 {
  background: black;
}

.btn--2 {
  background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Also adding @extend .button1 in .button2's hover worked. Is it the right way?

Comment: It works, but it's not the better solution because it's hard to read and to go back to the style that you are extending.

Comment: Thanks Denis... You solutions is better and up to the standards :)

Comment: is it possible to return a classname ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mixin](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin)

```
@mixin hoverStyle {
   &:hover{
     background: red;
   }
}

.button1 {
   background: blue;
   padding: 5px 10px;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: white;
   @include hoverStyle;
}

.button2 {
   background: blue;
   padding: 5px 10px;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: white;
   @include hoverStyle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. It worked for me
http://jsbin.com/lezuwalida/edit?html,css,output

the generated css looks same

```
.demon:hover, .demon.demo {
  outline: 3px solid red;
}

.demon2:hover, .demon2.demo2 {
  outline: 3px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

A good way to handle all this stuff is using variables also, 
for example if you define something like this:

```
$buttons-hover-color: #somecolor;
```

Then you can call it in any button and if int he future you wanna change it just change the variable and all the buttons will update.
Another important thing is that extend doesn't work in media queries, so maybe in the future when you are targeting mobile you don't wanna have that red in mobile so you just need to create a another var to it.

something like this:

```
$btn-hover-color: red;
$btn-hover-mobile: black;

.button1 {
 background: black;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 &:hover {
  background-color: $btn-hover-color;
 }
}

.button2 {
  background: blue;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  &:hover {
    background-color: $btn-hover-color;
  }

  @media (max-width: 800px) {
    &:hover {
      background-color: $btn-hover-mobile;
    }
  }
 }
```

Hope this help you

Comment: That's not what's being asked here.

Comment: I was asking about extends